# CameraUpdate, SupportMapFragment inside ViewPager, not loading second time

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-maps-v2

I'm facing problems when placing SupportMapFragment inside a fragment that is part of a viewpager with 5 tabs, everything works correctly when viewpager loads the map for first time, but not showing anything whe comming back from another tab. I load the map as follows:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_estate);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_estate, mapFragment).commit();
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

and then use it like:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.map = googleMap;
    this.map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    this.map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    this.map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false); 
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 16);
    mapFragment.getMap().moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Anyone facing same problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing`FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();` for `FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();` solved the problem.